# Discussion Board issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

For some reason in one of the site collection only, OOTB Discussion board app is not working. instead of default 3 columns 1) subject, 2) body and 3) question it is showing up lot of columns like 1) discussion title, 2) version 3) trimmed body 4) message id etc..

Even though we create new sub site, the same issue is happening.

is there any hidden feature for discussion board I have to activate/deactivate to fix the issue? Not sure if Discussion Board is corrupted in the site collection.

> logs shows: Getting Error Message for Exception
>   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid data has been used to update the
>   list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.

Comment: sounds like someone tried to edit the default view and made a mistake. If I were you I'd check the list view settings and see if there is anything out of place there that you can fix manually.

Comment: it is not issue with listview. when user click on "new discussion" all those extra columns are showing up.